# Shift key on custom iOS8 keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

im kinda new to coding so i just want to know if something i thought about is possible. I made this custom keyboard off a tutorial(objective-c). There's was no help on how to implement a shift key in the tutorial. So here's my thought. I have a XIB file with my custom keyboard with lower case which works probably. I want to create a new XIB file with upper cases letter but what would be the code to detect:

```
if (shiftKey) = touchupinside {
lowerCaseKeyboard = hidden
upperCaseKeyboard = not hidden }
```

I know this code doesn't work, i'm just trying to explain what i'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You will need to post more details about how you created your custom keyboard in order to know what needs to be done to hide it and display another.

Comment: Well, i figured changing the whole keyboard wasn't the way to do it. Having an action to toggle upper/lower cases when you tap shift is the way to do it but i still have no clue how to do it.